# help with actionscript 3 regex and xmpp stanzas

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, xmpp

i have a string:

```
<presence to="testsubject_1@server.org/d9ec56e4"
from="room@conference.server.org/testsubject_2">
<x xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user"><item affiliation="none"
role="visitor"/></x></presence>
```

how would i find out if it contains the presence attribute as well as who its from?
ive tried using as3's xml methods but they require that the xml is a complete document so i figure to use regex but its late and im lost so ill post before i go to sleep :)

```
if (string contains <presence to="){
    // get who its from
}
```

Comment: If the string also contains the "stream" tag then you should add it to code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

ARGH! I would highly recommend you don't use regex to parse XML, that's why we have XML parsers.

```
var raw_data:String = '<presence to="testsubject_1@server.org/d9ec56e4" from="room@conference.server.org/testsubject_2"> <x xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user"><item affiliation="none" role="visitor"/></x></presence>';
trace("raw_data:", raw_data);
var presence:XML = new XML(raw_data);
trace("presence:", presence);
trace("root name == presence:", (presence.localName() == "presence")); // [trace] root name == presence: true
trace("from:", presence.@from); // [trace] from: room@conference.server.org/testsubject_2
```

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/XML.html

Or just use one of the many XMPP libraries out there:

http://code.google.com/p/as3xmpp/

http://code.google.com/p/seesmic-as3-xmpp/

Comment: in this circumstance, this method does not work. xmpp exchanges stanzas, not complete xml documents (or structure type). if you do this you will get TypeError: Error #1085: The element type "stream" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</stream>".

Comment: Don't put the stream:stream start tag into the parser then, or use a SAX or pull parser.

Answer (score 0):

`/<(\w+)(( to|from)=\"([^\"]+)\")+>.*</\1>/`

Answer (score 0):

Search for: `/<presence\b(?=[^><]*\sto\s*=)[^><]*\sfrom\s*=\s*["']([^><"']*)["'].*?</presence>/gis`

`$1` will refer to who its from, e.g. `room@conference.server.org/testsubject_2`

It works even if `to`/`from` in a different order.
It works even if XML uses single quotes, but there must not be a single-quotes between single-quotes. I can improve this behaviour further, but the regex would become longer.

If you take malformed XML documents into account, you shouldn't use regex, use either DOM or XPath instead.

Comment: Won't work if the XML uses single quotes.  Won't work if to/from in a different order.  Won't work if an attribute contains > (which is well-formed, according to the AttValue production of http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/).  XML is harder than it looks.

Comment: I have just edited the regex again to fulfil the most of your request.